# How can i include a js File who is not in the same directory?

Tags: javascript, path

I hava a folder tests, were all my tests are in.
And i have a folder were all my programm code is in.

- TestsFolder
- ->Testfolder
- -->test.js
- CodesFolder
- ->Folder1
- -->code.js

Now i want to include the code.js into test.js.

Comment: Here You have all informations what You need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

**Relative path**:
Path depends on the current file directory. For example:

```
index.html

TestFolder \
            |- test.js

CodeFolder \
            |- code.js

innerPages \
            |- inner-page.html
            |- another-page.html
```

If the browser currently running the file named `inner-page.html`, you can access the code.js with relative path "`../CodeFolder/code.js`". The `../` means "parent directory".

You can use multiple times "parent directory" - `../../../SomeFolder/somefile.js` = go 3 directories up, and then find the `SomeFolder` and the file `somefile.js`.

**Absolute path**:
It means that you access the root folder (if server run your files, it means the server **public** folder). Absolute paths starts with "`/`". For example:

The absolute path: "`/CodeFolder/code.js`" will access the `code.js` file regardless from where you try to access it.

If the browser currently running `index.html`. The above absolute path will access the `code.js`. And if it currently running `inder-page.html` This absolute path will access `code.js` again.

**Keep in mind** that if this is a client-side project and it runs on the browser, the good practice is to use absolute paths instead of relative.

Imagine that you use `code.js` into `index.html` and all `innerPages`. In the future you need to restructure the folders of the project somehow. For example you need to add sub-directory in `innerPages` directory.

```
index.html

TestFolder \
            |- test.js

CodeFolder \
            |- code.js

innerPages \
            |- user-pages \
                           |- inner-page.html
                           |- another-page.html

            |- admin-pages \
                            |- ...
```

What's happening if you are used realtive paths? For example:
You are into `inner-page.html` and you are used this path: `"../CodeFolder/code.js"`.
This path will be incorrect in this case.

But if you using Absolute path... For example:
`"/CodeFolder/code.js"` - It will still work, because the `"/"` means the root directory. No matter where are you now, this path will search for `CodeFolder` in your root directory.

**Load the script**

As @Krzysztof Trzos noted, you can use [jQuery's getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) function to easy load the script from another script. Or you can see the full answer he commented for **non** jquery way.